# Write file in real time with C

Tags: c, real-time, fopen, printf

How may I write data into a file in real time?
I mean: A program gets data and puts them into a file (we can say *out.txt*) with a `fprintf(...)` command, then another program read data from the file (*out.txt*) and elaborates them.

I have a flow like this:

```
fp=fopen("out.txt","w+");

    while(...) {

    ...

    fprintf (fp,"\n %s", data);

}

fclose(fp);
```

With that flow I get data into the file (*out.txt*) after I have closed the file.

Is there a way to write data in real time into the file?

Comment: call fflush(fp) after each fprintf.

Comment: You want a named pipe, a message queue, or some other IPC mechanism.  You do *not* want to rely on an open file being written with "fprintf()" in process being in synch with "fread()" in another process.

Comment: Maybe look at using a FIFO.  `man fifo` if your platform supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mean *simultaneously* when you say *in real time*. Simultaneous access
to a file requires to open a shared file. This may be a pipe or some other interprocess
communication. It may also be a simple file on disk, as asked for. Windows allows to open
a shared file by means of [_fsopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx).

```
#include <share.h> // required for manifest constants for shflag parameter.

fp = _fsopen("out.txt","w+",_SH_DENYWR); // e.g. _SH_DENYWR denies write access
   .
while(...) {
   .
   .
```

Another process can read the file while it is open; no need to close the file beforehand. The other process may even write (with `shflag = _SH_DENYNO`). However, writing and reading simultaneously from different processes requires some more coding effort.

```
   .
  fprintf (fp,"%s\n", data); // you may want to have the /n "new line" after writing the data
   .
```

Not all the written content is always immedeately written to the file (physically). Therefore it is required to force the content to be writen to the file after the `fprintf`.

```
   .
  fflush(fp); // force writing to device    
   .
}
```